# Launch an anchor after index is load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, I´m not programmer so I can´t handle this at all.
I need to launch a part of a website after index is loaded. I´ve been trying some jquery without any luck, ie this:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#tensa-inicio').trigger('click');
    },1000);
});
```

You can see the site in this url: 3w[dot]tensa[dot]es. I need to display the HOME link after index is loaded, but can´t see how to do this.

Any help is really appreciated.

TIA!

Comment: the given url redirects to tensa[dot]com

Comment: are you trying to show an anchor tag once the page has loaded? or are you trying to trigger a click on an anchor tag once the page has loaded?

Comment: iAmClownShoe... the page redirects to /EN/index.html due a php language script, so you must see it in english. When loaded, it shown an index "index.html#!/page-home", and I need after that to launch the HOME top menu link, which is "#tensa-inicio" anchor... That will contain a text in the middle. I´m gonna update it via FTP, right now, so give me 5 mins before reloading.

Comment: Sorry all, my mistake!!! it was 3w[dot]tensa[dot]es

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you are trying to fire click event for the Anchor tag, You can make it work with following script too

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = $('#tensa-inicio').attr('href');
    },1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "tensa-inicio" is the ID of anchor element in the document, you better call the native `click()` method rather than the jQuery event:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var oLink = $('#tensa-inicio');
    if oLink.length === 1)
        oLink[0].click();
},1000);
```

Comment: What exactly is the "tensa-inicio"? Can you post the HTML for that element?

Answer (score 0):

This was the tweak:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){    
        $("#sliderpromo").easySlider({
            //auto: true, 
            //continuous: true,
            speed:500,
            pause:6000,
            numeric: true
        }, window.location="#!/tensa-inicio");
    });    
</script>
```

Now, every time index is loaded, that ID is loaded... ; )
Thanks to ALL!